# How do I compile a C++ Arduino Mocking library into my VSCode project with CMake?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, makefile, arduino

I apologize in advance, I'm learning all of this as I go, so I might be overly verbose since I don't know what is important to mention.

A little bit of environment background, I'm on a Windows 11 machine with mingw64 installed.

I write my code in VSCode, and I'm just learning how to use CTests with CMake.

The code I'm trying to test is Arduino based, so I'm trying to use an Arduino Mocking library I found through PlatformIO https://github.com/FabioBatSilva/ArduinoFake

My CMake file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14) # version can be different
project(TestProject) #name of your project

# Set compilation flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -flto=1")
include(CTest)
include(FetchContent)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/arduinofake-src/src)

enable_testing()
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  # Specify the commit you depend on and update it regularly.
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/5376968f6948923e2411081fd9372e71a59d8e77.zip
)

# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

# Fetch ArduinoFake library
FetchContent_Declare(
    ArduinoFake
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/FabioBatSilva/ArduinoFake.git
    GIT_TAG cf9c596b73ffe7e7cf39faeb550bbef8598edb98
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ArduinoFake)

# Now simply link against gtest or gtest_main as needed. Eg
add_executable(mytests mytests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mytests gtest)
add_test(NAME example_test COMMAND mytests)
```

My tests are really as simple as it gets and worked fine before I added the ArduinoFake stuff to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
TEST(myfunctions, add)
{
    GTEST_ASSERT_EQ(add(10, 22), 32);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

When I call make, however I get the following error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable main-d.exe
lto-wrapper.exe: warning: using serial compilation of 2 LTRANS jobs
lto-wrapper.exe: note: see the '-flto' option documentation for more information
lto1.exe: error: two or more sections for .gnu.lto__ZN10SerialTest19test_extends_streamEv.4317.e9bafa65
(null):0: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
lto-wrapper.exe: fatal error: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [_deps/arduinofake-build/test/main-d.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_deps/arduinofake-build/test/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I googled the error lto1.exe: error: two or more sections, and only found this, which didn't seem to help.
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94271

I also tried adding set_target_properties(matrixTests PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-allow-multiple-definition")
to my CMake file as well as changing set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -flto=1") to set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-lto") to no avail.

I'm just lost as to what this error means. I've checked the code and don't see two definitions of anything? I even tried deleting my "build" folder and running cmake + build again, but the same error shows up.

If I remove the -flto flag, the error I get is

```
C:\Users\share\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2RBUHc.s: Fatal error: can't write 104 bytes to section .text of CMakeFiles\main.dir\main.cpp.obj: 'file too big'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe: CMakeFiles\main.dir\main.cpp.obj: too many sections (104018)
```

which is why I added it in the first place.

Anyone more experienced in CMake able to help me understand what's going wrong?

Thanks so much, I appreciate any help or questions as to how I could make this clearer.